# Скачивание фото из БД по file_id aiogram

Tags: python, база-данных, telegram-bot, aiogram

Всем привет, использую яп python библиотеку aiogram
Появилась необходимость скачать все фото по file_id которые берутся из БД

```
    @dp.message_handler(commands='xyz', state=["*"])
async def start(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    hent = db.hentai_db()
    for hnt in hent:
        await bot.download_file_by_id(file_id = hnt[1],destination = f'{hnt[0]}.png',chunk_size=99999999999999999)
```

Попробовал скачивать таким способом но разрешение у изображений оставляют лучшего, что можно с этим сделать, или возможно нужно использовать какой-нибудь другой способ загрузки

Comment: Добрый день, а вы уверены, что в бд Id картинок высокого качества? Насколько я помню у photo в телеграме несколько id для разных разрешений может быть выбран не тот id.

Comment: Да при сохранении в бд получал самое высокое разрешение

Comment: Скорее всего сжимает телеграм. Надо фотки грузить не как photo, а как document.